# Wordpress CSS - problems with image buttons in menu disappearing when hovered over

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to add custom images for social follow link buttons to my website sidebar menu. Right now I am stuck on the Facebook one as my first test, but ideally want to add others later. (which I am realizing might not be easy with the method I have chosen)

I tried using various methods, the most success I have gotten so far is the method at DIY Themes ([this article](http://diythemes.com/thesis/rtfm/replace-wp-menu-text-links-image-sprites/)) and on my site style.css the code I added is below:

```
#menu-item-127 a {
    display:block; 
    height:83px; width:75px; 
    padding:0px; 
    margin-left:6px; 
    outline:none; 
    /*text-indent:-9999px;*/
    background-image:url('/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Grunge-Facebook-Stamp-small-sprite.png');
    background-position:0 -82px;
}

#menu-item-127 a:hover { background-position:0 0px; }
```

***The problem is that when you hover over the link the background image disappears,*** it does not transition to the "active" version of the sprite as it should.

Secondly the text does not indent off the screen, but stays on top of the image (I know that part is commented out in the code above, because I turned it on and off to test what was going on, doesn't make a difference)

Third problem is that the hover activation area is to large, it stretches the entire width of the menu bar instead of just right on top of the image. So if you are to the right of the image it is still considered "hovering", even though you cannot click on the FB link.

It seems to be related to some other part of my style.css because even if I remove the a:hover part of the above code it still makes the background image disappear. I have adjusted every variable and inspected every element that I know how, I am stumped on this.

My website is americagonepostal.com. The base theme is Hum.

BTW, I have never really done CSS before. I am doing this site as a favor for my cousin who is totally tech retarded, but is an artist so has very specific aesthetic expectations. I have just been hacking away without any idea what I am doing so if there is a better way to put images with links in that side-menu area, I am all ears. It does not necessarily have to "highlight" when you hover, but that would be a nice touch.

Ideally I'd like to add Facebook, Twitter and RSS buttons in the same grungy stamp style, but horizontally. Is that possible to fit all 3 buttons on one horizontal using custom menus as I have done?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the back ground image in your a:hover as well as a tag? It might also be that you need to really drill down and specify your CSS exactly, eg: #wrapper #div #menu #menu-item-127 a:hover { sometimes CSS can be finicky if theres lots of it

Comment: I did try specifying the image url in the a:hover, but did not matter.

Also, tried all sorts of other class and ID tags for the item, anything remotely related to it in the chrome inspect. It only works with exactly #menu-item-<num> . If I try to add identifiers with either hash (#) or dot (.) (which I understand are id's vs classes, tried both ways) it breaks it again

However, took Aruna Hew's suggetion and put the '!important' property in both the main tag URL and the a:hover background position does make the roll-over highlighting work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#menu-item-127 a:hover {
background: url("/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Grunge-Facebook-Stamp-small-sprite.png") !important;
```

The **!important** will override any inherited styles

Text Indenting : Change text-align property in the branding section:

```
#branding { border: 0 none;
            bottom: 0; 
            padding-top: 5em; 
            text-align: none;
            top: 0; }
```

Then override the same way:

```
#menu-item-131 a:hover { background-position: 0 0 !important; 
                         text-indent: -999px !important;}
```

This is only for a:hover if you need the normal state to be affected as well you have to use in-line styling ( not the best practice but in this case will solve the problem) :

```
 <li id="menu-item-131" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-131" style="text-indent:-999px"> <a href="facebook.com/AmericaGonePostal"; target="_blank">fb</a> </li>
```

Third problem of hover activation area being too large:

```
#menu-item-131 a{ background-position: 0 0 !important; 
                 text-indent: -999px !important;
                 width:75px !important; }
```

Comment: awesome, that fixed the highlighting issue! I will keep working around the other issues as best I can.

Comment: Text Indenting can also be overridden the same way:

#menu-item-131 a:hover {
    background-position: 0 0 !important;
    text-indent: -177px !important;

Comment: But this is only for a:hover if you need the normal state to be affected as well you have to use in-line styling ( not the best practice but in this case will solve the problem) :


<li id="menu-item-131" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-131" **style="text-indent:-999px**">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/AmericaGonePostal" target="_blank">fb</a>
</li>

Comment: For the above to work you need to change text-align property in the branding section:

#branding {
    border: 0 none;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 5em;
    **text-align: none;**
    top: 0;
}

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made the change to branding and added the !important tags and to indenting and the hover is working fine now, and the "fb" text is gone for both hover and normal state. GREAT! However I still have it highlighting in a 180px span mostly to the right of the FB button. I tried adding !important in the Width 75px property, no dice.

Comment: Ignore above comment... forgot to add the important tag to background-position property. Now it works %100, only highlights directly above image! Did not have to use In-line-styling, Awesome. Out of curiosity, **Would it be possible to add 2-3 more images with different URLs horizontally next to the Facebook Stamp?** (Such as a Twitter and RSS image links). I can repeat this process to list them vertically down the page, but it would be a better use of space if I could get all the image/links on one horizontal line. Possible or too complex? Thanks again! First time on StackO, Great response!

Comment: Very happy to help friend, Yes it is possible to have images horizontally and you can get an idea how here : 

http://jsfiddle.net/arunahewapathirane/BKYFg/1/

Floating the div's left will line them up horizontally but WordPress
generates it's html structure through php so you will have to dig deep and study the WordPress code, once you understand how and where WordPress generates the html you will know where to put the additional markup. Some learning curve is there but if you need help we are always here :-)

Comment: Watch the videos here, helped me immensley when I was first pulling my hair out struggling to understand the wordpress internals, it's loop and how things are done.. :-)

http://css-tricks.com/designing-for-wordpress-complete-series-downloads/